# adding two different groups of ec2 instances to aws_elb

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My question is if I have something like this in `aws_elb` block for `dataAnode` ec2 instance group  [this works as expected ]

```
instances = ["${aws_instance.dataAnode.*.id}"]
```

but now I have `dataBnode` group of instances.

can I do this ?

```
instances = ["${aws_instance.dataAnode.*.id}", "${aws_instance.dataBnode.*.id}"]
```

basically how do I have one list from these two different types of `aws_isntance` groups?

I have not tried using `concat` menthod, but if that is the only way, I can go for it... any suggestions would be appreciated

I use Terraform v0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [concat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#concat-list1-list2-):

```
instances = "${concat(aws_instance.dataAnode.*.id, aws_instance.dataBnode.*.id)}"
```